# Capitalisation of domain names and URLs

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use capitalization when mentioning a domain name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41695/should-i-use-capitalization-when-mentioning-a-domain-name)

Is there a rule or preference for capitalisation of domain names?

I'm aware that folder and file names are case sensitive, but should domain names (particularly with proper nouns) be capitalised?

www.joeblogswidgets.com

or

www.JoeBlogsWidgets.com

Comment: Note: the part of a URL following the domain name _is_ case sensitive, so capitalization is fixed by the site.

Comment: As a software developer I find that using PascalCase like in this question enhances readability if the domain name is made up of multiple words. I don't know if this is true for non-programmers as well, 'though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule, as domain names are not case sensetive.

The preference would be to follow the convention, to be as little confusing as possible. The convention is not to capitalise domain names, so that is generally what people expect.

If you feel like capitalasing a domain name, it's up to you do decide if it's warranted. You should also consider if you should change the domain name instead of changing how you write it, like for example how *www.expertsexchange.com* was changed to *www.experts-exchange.com*.