# "thecanadianecyclopedia.com" vs. "TheCanadianEncylopedia.com": which is better for an in-text citation?

Tags: capitalization, mla

When making an in-text citation for a website, in MLA format, do you capitalize the first letter of each word?

For example: (thecanadianecyclopedia.com)

or

(TheCanadianEncylopedia.com)

Comment: Related: [Should I use capitalization when mentioning a domain name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41695)

Answer (score 1):

The capitalization of URLs is never directly mentioned in the *MLA Handbook* (8th ed.)

However, Section 2.5.2 (URLs and DOIs) does refer to it indirectly:

> When giving a URL, copy it in full from your Web browser, but omit *http://* or *https://*.

Since I know of no web browser that retains capitalization after reaching a site, I can only assume that if we follow these instructions, we will always end up with a URL that's in lowercase.